# Write code to switch the order of the winners list so that it is now A to Z by last name. Assign this list to the variable z_winners

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Write code to switch the order of the winners list so that it is now A to Z by last name. Assign this list to the variable z_winners.

I know it shouldn't use winners[-1] but how can I sort it by last name

```
winners = ['Alice Munro', 'Alvin E. Roth', 'Kazuo Ishiguro', 'Malala Yousafzai', 'Rainer Weiss', 'Youyou Tu']
for n in winners:
z_winners = sorted(winners[-1], reverse = True)
```

Comment: can you post the sample list and expected output

Comment: `winners[-1]` is not a list it's last element in the list

Comment: I used this website for the first time. I don't know why some of them(sample) disappeared. sorry now I have modified the question...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
winners = ['Alice Munro', 'Alvin E. Roth', 'Kazuo Ishiguro', 'Malala Yousafzai', 'Rainer Weiss', 'Youyou Tu']
z_winners = sorted(winners, key= lambda x: x.split()[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
['Kazuo Ishiguro',
 'Alice Munro',
 'Alvin E. Roth',
 'Youyou Tu',
 'Rainer Weiss',
 'Malala Yousafzai']
```

Comment: I was looking up the same thing, thanks for your help!